# Checking Riemann integrability

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as  $\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
 \frac{1}{n} & \textrm{ for }x =\frac{1}{n} \textrm{ where } n \in \mathbb{N}\\
0 & \textrm{ otherwise}
\end{array}\right.
\end{eqnarray*}$.

Is the function Riemann integrable? How do I check this using upper and lower Riemann integrals? Upper Darboux sum for arbitrary partitions is where I am stuck.

Also if the usual integral $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$ exists can I say the function is Riemann integrable? and is there anything wrong in the following arguments?:

$$\int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{1}f(x)dx=\int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{n-1}}f(x)dx+\cdots+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}f(x)dx$$
$$=\int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{n-1}}0dx+\cdots+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}0dx$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\int_{\frac{1}{i+1}}^{\frac{1}{i}}0dx$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{1}f(x)dx=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\int_{\frac{1}{i+1}}^{\frac{1}{i}}0dx$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}0dx=0.$$

Comment: Can you solve the case of regular partitions?

Comment: try tu generalize my argument: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1524611/prove-any-function-f-is-riemann-integrable-if-it-is-bounded-and-continuous-exc

Comment: @Did: For $P=\{1,\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},0\}$, $U(P,f)=0+0+\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}\frac{1}{4}=\frac{2}{15}$

Comment: @Did: regular partition means the length of every subintervals is same, right?

Comment: Yes it does. In the regular partition $P=\{k/n\mid0\leqslant k\leqslant n\}$, what is the total length of the intervals with $k\geqslant\sqrt{n}$ containing some point $x$ with $f(x)\ne0$? What is a bound of the contribution of the intervals with $k\leqslant\sqrt{n}$? Thus?

Comment: A simpler way is to use the Lebesgue's theorem that characterize Riemann integrability. 

Note that $f$ is discontinuous and only discontinuous at $x := 1/n$ for each $n \geq 1$; the set $\{ 1/n \mid n \geq 1\}$ has measure zero; hence by the Lebesgue's theorem $f$ is Riemann-integrable.

If you want to use the argument you added, you have to prove the existence of each integral.

Comment: It seems that you want to use approximation anyway, then you can use the following fact: If $f: [a, d] \to\mathbb R$ is bounded and $f: [c, d] \to \mathbb R$ is Riemann integrable for all $c >a$, then $f $ is also Riemann integrable and $\int_a^d f(x) dx = \lim_{c\to a^+} \int_c^d f(x) dx$. (Searching the proof now....)

Comment: In short, there is nothing wrong in your argument (given the result I mentioned)

Comment: @JohnMa "given the result I mentioned" Precisely. There are tons of results more advanced than the one the OP is interested in that one can appeal to to "deduce" it. It is not clear to me what this achieves (but it is true that the question is not crystal clear about the tools that are allowed to solve the problem).

Comment: @Did: I couldn't follow it. $k\ge\sqrt{n}$, n=9, length=1/9; n=16, length=1/16;n=25, length=3/25? I am not getting it.

Comment: It might be time to stop plugging in small values of $n$ to try to discern a pattern... For **every** $n$, how many points $x$ where $f(x)\ne0$ between $1/\sqrt{n}$ and $1$?

Comment: @Did:Number of integers between 0 and $\sqrt{n}$. Since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\le \frac{1}{i}\implies i\le \sqrt{n} $

Comment: Right. So, next step in the precise procedure suggested in my second comment above?

Comment: length of the intervals which contain them? $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is an upperbound for it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea for showing that the upper integral is also zero.

Fix a large integer $n>0$.

- Use a partition such that:

  - $[0,1/n]$ is the first subinterval,
  - The numbers $1/1,1/2,\ldots,1/(n-1)$ are all isolated from the rest of $[0,1]$ by tiny subintervals of width $<1/n^2$. This forces several subintervals containing none of the numbers $1/k$, but that's the point really.
- Then show that the upper sum related to the above partition is less than $2/n^2$. With an appropriate choice of $n$ this will be as small as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that the lower integral is zero.

For the upper integral, take a partition with the points $0, 1/k, 2/k, \dots, 1$

Then in the sum $$\sum f(c_k) \Delta x_k$$ with each $c_k$ chosen arbitrarily in the interval, this sum is at most $\dfrac1k \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{1}{n} = O\left(\frac{\log k}{k}\right)$. So fix $\varepsilon > 0$ and taking $k$ will make the upper integral at most $\varepsilon$.

Thus the upper and lower integrals coincide.